# Nginx container increase memory use after sending metadata of videos on binded volume

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, memory, video

I have an AWS server with a docker containers running there
Server contains a lot of mp4 videos (few hundred GB)
Every video is ~ 30 MB

One of the services is a React app that allow to watch videos one by one but total videos on the page is 5-20

Every time when i open the page with videos that was never watched the nginx container will add 50-150 MB to memory usage and eventually entire app will be frozen.

App is not for high loads (1-2 users at once) so i use

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

client_max_body_size 5M;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`
```

in nginx settings.

Also container is simply bound to directory with videos.

Interesting thing is that after restarting the container memory usage will drop to normal 2-3 MB and will not rise if i will open the page that was opened in last few days

So issue is reproducible only with old pages that contains videos that very old

Inside nginx container all is calm and good, memory usage of processes and workers are minimal so i don't even know 'who' exactly is using memory

Does anyone have ideas where to dig to try fix this unwanted 'caching'?

react code is pretty long so I can't really share it all here but in general its one video for component so inside the smallest component it looks like that:

```
   import React 'react';
    const EVideo = ({
                      props,
                    }) => {
      const onLoad = e => {// some logic to set initial playback rate}

  const onTimeUpdate = e => {//some logic to calculate video time into business logic time}

  return
  (<><video
    ref={videoRef}
    poster={props.poster}
    src={props.video_path}
    onLoadedMetadata={onLoad}
    onTimeUpdate={onTimeUpdate}
    playsInline
  />
    <div>Here business logic results will be shown</div>
  </>)
}
```

Comment: Can you show your nginx.conf file and the react code where you're showing the videos?

Comment: Yes, sure
but from react I hide business logic

Comment: This might have to do with preloading behaviour of the browser you're using. See [preload attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload). Different browsers have different default value. Try explicitly setting it to `none`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rahul Sharma!
This totally changes the behavior of page loading
I don't yet know if its possible to like an answer but you really help!)

Comment: I'm adding an answer to help others now that the issue is found. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to preloading behaviour of the browser you're using. The browser is prefetching the video that it has not seen yet. You can control this default behaviour of your browser using `preload` attribute of video element.

Setting `preload=none` inside video element should prevent your browser from prefetching the videos. Read more about `preload` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload).

Comment: I upload it to demo server and now I can see that while this was super effective in case of requests qty, the actual issue still there.
For every video that I play docker container with Nginx will gain ~30-40 MB of RAM usage. This RAM will stack and not lowers when I close the tab or the browser itself.

It's much better to not gain +200 MB on every page but the deep reason for this problem is still there somewhere((

With any caching option disabled it still looks like the container caches the video

Comment: Try setting this variable `sendfile_max_chunk` to some value, may be `2m` like this: `sendfile_max_chunk 2m;` below `sendfile on;` line in your nginx file. And setting `keepalive_timeout` to a lower value and see if that helps.

Comment: And could you please show the `location` block which you're using to serve your videos?

Comment: The location is described as simply as possible
`    location ~ data {
        root /;
    }`

as for sendfile_max_chunk 2m and keepalive_timeout
I try 2 and 1 mb  and timeout 5 , 10 , 20 sec

no difference at all (

still every video load at least a half of itself to RAM